# Angular2 : How to call an WebAPI method that accepts ODataQueryOptions

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api2, odata

I am not able to find a way to pass in the ODataQueryOptions from Angular2 Component.

Can this be done? if so any reference to example or links appreciated

Answer (score 0):

ODataQueryOptions are just a translation of a RequestURI, so you actually can directly pass in an Uri to the ODataController which will then automatically be translated into ODataQueryOptions:

```
http://www.example.com/api/Endpoint/ThingsController?$skip=1
```

This Uri will then automatically be translated to query options as shown below:

[image: ODataQueryOptions.Skip]

As I am no Angular expert, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42237043/3881834) for an example on how to send a request to an ODataController (but use `applicatoin/json` as opposed to the value in the example). But basically you only have to append your query parameters to the base uri (which you can easily parameterise as shown in the example).