# OData Patch is not updating the database

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, odata, patch

I have a WebApi 2 controller. I want to use OData Patch on one of the controllers. Here's what I did so far.

I added the following line in WebApiConfig

```
config.MapODataServiceRoute("odata", "odata", GenerateEdmModle());
private static Microsoft.OData.Edm.IEdmModel GenerateEdmModle()
{
    var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
    builder.EntitySet<Auth>("Auths");
        
    return builder.GetEdmModel();
}
```

Then in the controller, This is how I'm trying to use patch method

```
[HttpPatch]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PatchAuth(int id, Delta<Auth> value)
{
    var auth = await db.Auth.FindAsync(id);
    if (auth == null) return NotFound();

    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(auth.direction, auth.id);
    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Patching");
        
    try
    {
        value.Patch(auth);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.Message);
        return InternalServerError(e);
    }
    return Ok(value);
}
```

And here's how I'm sending it from angular service

```
// patch auth
service.patchAuth = function (authId, auth) {

    var request = $http({
        method: 'PATCH',
        url: baseUrl + 'api/Auths',
        data: JSON.stringify(auth),
        params: { id: authId },
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
    });

    return (request.then(handleSuccess, handleError));
}
```

Here's what I see in Fiddler
[image]

I see that the controller finds the Patch Method, and seems like it's trying to update, but the value never gets update.

I also add a breakpoint at `value.Patch(auth)` and checked the `changedProperties`, but there's nothing. I've been trying to find out what's causing this but haven't got a clue.

Comment: I am facing the same issue but only with integer type values. string and bool values are updating but not integer. any idea why? i have tried everything in postman. It has wasted my 3 days

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You specified `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` as your content type. Instead you have to use `application/json`.

When you specify `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` the call is still routed to the correct patch handler (as in your case), however no changed properties are passed into `Delta<T>` by Web.Api.

When you examine the *raw* HTTP Request in Fiddler your call should more look like this:

```
PATCH http://www.example.com/api/Auths(5) HTTP/1.1
Content-Type: application/json
Host: www.example.com
Content-Length: 20

{ "id" : 123456789 }
```

Comment: I had tried both ways, and perhaps more. It was finding the function, but only wasn't updating the property. I found JsonPatch as I was trying to find the solution for this. It was very easy to use and worked exactly like I wanted. More info on JsonPatch can be found at http://jsonpatch.com/

Comment: thanks for the update! I had a look at jsonpatch and this looks interesting. Maybe I can make use of this in some of my projects. 
However, there must have been something wrong with your previous implementation, as `PATCH` is working correctly as described in several of our projects. Still thanks for the link!

Comment: You're welcome. I'm sure I'm missing something with my previous implementation like you said.